# Make a copy of file from shared google drive to my google drive with Google Drive API v3 C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

My colleague shared with me a lot of university documents and I want to copy them to my google drive.

I start C# .net core application and Google Drive v3 API.

I have

```
  var request = _dataService.Files.Get(id);
  request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
  request.Fields = "*";

  return request;
```

Where `dataService`

```
  _dataService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
  {
    ApiKey = settingsData.ApiKey,
    ApplicationName = settingsData.ApplicationName
  });
```

How to copy files ? He sent me file ids so I have access to that file id. How to `make a copy` to my google drive ? I didn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: Not helpful. I need to make a copy, not upload file !

Comment: You can do it with the UI. Click the `Shared With Me` select all. `Right Click -> Make a copy`

Comment: If I would do with UI, I wouldn't ask here. I have hundreds of files...I want to do programatically

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you cannot use the method [`Copy`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1FilesResource_1_1CopyRequest.html)?

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File copiedFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
//This will be the body of the request so probably you would want to modify this
copiedFile.Name = "Name of the new file";

string originFileId = "insert fileId to be copied";

FilesResource.CopyRequest copyRequest = service.Files.Copy(copiedFile, originFileId);
// You can change more parameter of the request here

copyRequest.Execute();
```

You can modify the body of the request through the File object (`copiedFile`) you can look at the parameters in [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy).

Make sure that you include all relevant scopes.

If you still have doubts about the fields or methods in C# classes you can take a deeper look at the [C# doc for the api](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/).

Also I would suggest to try the [Quickstart for .NET Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) and work from there in case the solution above don't work.

Comment: Need to be authorized to do such operation

Comment: Yes, you need to have authorization using the normal OAuth flow. Also the files need to be shared with he account which you want to copy the files to.